# JavaScript Regex should be only containing N numeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need javascript regexp to validate some pattern like

```
745128
745128, 184122
745128, 184122, 425412
```

each comma separated value should be only containing 6 numeric characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
^\d{6}(?:,\s\d{6})*$
```

OR

Added a second option because i don't know clearly about the spaces in-between.

```
^\d{6}(?:,\s*\d{6})*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xE6aD0/5)

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
\d{6}                    digits (0-9) (6 times)
(?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                         times):
  ,                        ','
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
  \d{6}                    digits (0-9) (6 times)
)*                       end of grouping
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\s*\d{6},?)+$
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/16

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{6}(?:,\s*\d{6})*$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/sQ8nV9/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh yea , i dont have the habit of refreshing the page while posting answers :p